# How to supply user and password to download USGS data with wget?

Tags: modis, shell

I think that http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/ has recently applied a login and pass authentication to retrieve data. 
my script was working before, but now it comes with an error 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.

I have login and pass, so how and where do I put it in the script?

```
#!/bin/sh

  for YEAR in  2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 ;
  do
     wget -r -l1 -p -nd -e robots=off -A "*h17v03*","*h18v03*" -R .jpg -R .xml http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD13Q1.005/$YEAR.07.03

wget -r -l1 -p -nd -e robots=off -A "*h17v03*","*h18v03*" -R .jpg -R .xml http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD13Q1.005/$YEAR.07.04
done 


#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: [this looks like a duplicate of this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4272770/5158630)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the LP DAAC access requires authentication (as of [20 July 2016](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/about/news_archive/important_changes_lp_daac_data_access)). You need to use your ["Earthdata" login](https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/home) (not USGS login, if you've previously been coming in from there).

You also need to authorise that Earthdata login on the Earthdata profile page.

USGS provided some [command line tips](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/get_data/docs/Command%20Line%20Access%20Tips%20for%20Utilizing%20Earthdata%20Login.docx), of which the following is in the `wget` specific section:

```
wget -L --load-cookies ~/.cookies --save-cookies ~/.cookies http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09A1.006/2001.01.09/MOD09A1.A2001009.h13v01.006.2015140120258.hdf
```

The reason why the `--username` and `--password` options don't appear is that best practice is to use a `.netrc` file, which looks like:

```
machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov
        login username
        password userpassword
```

(or whichever other machines in the data pool you are using).

Comment: how to use the .netrc file?

Comment: This is included in the command line tips document, it just goes into the user directory. Make sure you have the right permissions on that file (again, read the documented link and wget manual). If you can't use that, and you have the security environment that supports it, use --username and --password. Its not a good solution in general though.